# Long delay before playback in Flash JWPlayer

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, flv

I've got a Flash video that takes a very long time (30 seconds+) to load, which is obviously frustrating for users. I'm using the JWPlayer to embed the video.

Flash experts (which is not me), what am I doing wrong? Or is the video file too big/server too slow? I've tried embedding in various ways (direct embed, swfobject) without change.

I notice it does sometimes play right away on load, but I'm not sure if this is because at that time, the Flash video is cached in my browser.

[The link is here](http://kasiantest.bjornthomson.com/jim-pattison-outpatient-care-surgery-centre/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big / what bitrate is your video file? You could try checking the bandwidth somehow to see if the problem is with the hosting company.

Also you could try using Flowplayer, seems they have some dynamic stream switching based on bandwidth: http://flowplayer.electroteque.org/bwcheck